# python index out of range for a helper/function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, for-loop, slice

I am making a function that takes in a string and returns all possibilities of outputs, using the following transformations:

```
o -> 0  i,l -> 1
z -> 2  e -> 3
a -> 4  s -> 5
b -> 6  t -> 7
b -> 8  g,q -> 9
```

For example:

```
print(transform_digits("Bow"))
['Bow', 'B0w', '6ow', '60w', '8ow', '80w']
```

Here is the helper function that I use to get a transformation of a string `st` at an index `i`:

```
def position_transform(st,i):
    letter=st[i]
    front = st[:i]
    back=st[(i+1):]
    l=[]
    if (letter=="o" or letter=="O"): l.append(front+"0"+back)
    elif (letter=="z" or letter=="Z"): l.append(front+"2"+back)
    elif (letter=="a" or letter=="A"): l.append(front+"4"+back)
    elif (letter=="b" or letter=="B"):
        l.append(front+"6"+back)
        l.append(front+"8"+back)
    elif (letter=="i" or letter=="I"or letter=="l" or letter =="L"): l.append(front+"1"+back)
    elif (letter=="e" or letter=="E"): l.append(front+"3"+back)
    elif (letter=="s" or letter=="S"): l.append(front+"5"+back)
    elif (letter=="t" or letter=="T"): l.append(front+"7"+back)
    elif (letter=="g" or letter=="G"or letter=="q" or letter =="Q"): l.append(front+"9"+back)
    return l
```

Here is the main function:

```
def transform_digits(st):
    l=[]
    l.append(st)
    newl=l[:]
    length=len(st)
    for x in range(0,length):
        for i in l:
            s=position_transform(i,x)
            newl.append(s)
        l=newl[:]
    return l
```

when I run the main function I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in transform_digits
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in position_transform
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not exactly sure where this error is.  I've tried running `position_transform` on strings and that seems to work out fine, and my logic for the other functions seems fine, not sure where the index error is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `newl.append(s)`. You're appending the result of your `position_transform(i,x)` to your list, except `position_transform` returns a list, so you end up with lists inside lists. That means that, down the line, you try to `position_transform` and pass a list instead of a string. The list only has a few (1-2) items in it, far less than a string would have characters, leading to your `IndexError`.

If you want to append *the contents of a list* to another list, use the `[1:1]` [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/2386185), so your assignment would become `newl[1:1] = s`. So your nested `for-loop` now looks like this:

```
for x in range(0,length):
    for i in l:
        s=position_transform(i,x)
        newl[1:1] = s
    l=newl[:]
```

This makes the program execute fine, as far as I can tell.

In the future, I recommend choosing to use more descriptive variable names, and trying to comment your code as you write it. Otherwise you may end up staring at fucntions that you wrote 5 minutes ago, wondering what's going on in there. Writing maintainable code is very important!

Comment: Yeah obviously I would comment and have better var names if the functions get more complicated, I was used to append combining 2 lists in the previous language I learned, good to know that I have to do it this way.

Comment: Specially when asking questions on Stack Overflow, the more readable your code is, the more likely you are to get help (and quicker) :)

Comment: do you mean `newl.extend(s)`?

Comment: Sure, but his code uses a lot of slicing (such as `[:]`, `[:i]`, ...), so I used the slice notation equivalent to `extend` to keep it consistent.

Comment: good point, ill make my code more readable when I post on here

Comment: oh ok so I can use extend as well, also good to know, the previous language I used append for you could write list @ list where @ is append and it combines them